# Family research in Aden Colony

Tags: address, aden

I am researching my paternal side's family history. They lived in **Aden Colony** during the **British Colonisation** **in 1839-1967 (128 years)** and left **Aden** in **1967**.

They used to own **property** in **Aden** during that time. I am trying to find the **address** on Google Maps, but unfortunately, the names of the **roads** have been **changed**.

How can I find **old road names** in Aden?

I want to find the present-day address of that property.